# Why does a surface F(x,y,z) that never fold back on itself have $\nabla F$ $\cdot \vec{p} \neq 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces

[image]

[image]

Why does an implicit surface F(x,y,z) that never fold back on itself have $\nabla F$ $\cdot \vec{p} \neq 0$?

Comment: So why isn't the gradient ever perpendicular to the normal vector $\vec{p}$?

Comment: Do you know the result that $\nabla F$ is orthogonal to the level surfaces of $F$?

Comment: I know that $\nabla{F}$ is orthogonal to the level curves of F. So does that mean $\nabla{F}$ is always parallel to $\vec{p}$? Additionally in what direction would the gradient point at if we had a cylinder be a surface?

Comment: No, it is not necessarily parallel to $p$. However, $p$ is *not* parallel to the plane, so that it is not orthogonal to $\nabla F$. This is enough to guaruntee the dot product is non-zero

Comment: Why does a surface that folds back on itself like a cylinder have a p parallel "to the plane"? I can't imagine how the vectors would point or look like in such a case. May I have drawing please?

Comment: if you had a cylinder, the projection 'shadow' would be a disk. If you take $p$ to be any vector on the boundary of this disk which is orthogonal to the shadow, then it will be parallel to the sides cylinder, and thus orthogonal to the gradient at that point.

Comment: What About a bowl?

Comment: Aren’t the gradient at the edge of the bowl perpendicular to that normal vector p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption $\nabla F({\bf x})\ne{\bf 0}$ for all ${\bf x}\in S$ guarantees that each point ${\bf x}\in S$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that within $U$ the surface behaves as desired: no self-intersections, cusps, etc. One then can select a variable, say $z$, such that within $U$ the surface $S$ appears as graph of a $C^1$-function $z=\psi(x,y)$. The assumption $\nabla F({\bf x})\cdot{\bf p}\ne0$, whereby ${\bf p}=(0,0,1)$, enforces that we can actually choose $z$ as this "special" variable.

In points ${\bf x}\in S$ where $\nabla F({\bf x})\cdot{\bf p}=0$ the gradient of $F$, while $\ne{\bf 0}$,  is parallel to the $(x,y)$-plane. Therefore the tangent plane of $S$ is *vertical* in such points. This has the consequence that in the neighborhood of such points the surface $S$ is still smooth, but it does not project properly onto the $(x,y)$-plane.

Comment: What about a bowl surface? It doesn’t fold back on itself but at the very edge that you put your lips on to drink isn’t the gradient orthogonal to the normal vector of the ground?

Comment: What about the famous red cup that drunk college students drink from? Where you put your lips on it isn’t the gradient orthogonal to the normal vector p?

Comment: Yes, this is all true, but the author of your source wants to exclude such points for the calculations he has in mind.

Comment: How do you know the author of the book George B Thomas and company wants to exclude such points for the calculations?

Comment: Is a bowl a cusp surface?